# How to pass multiple annotations in an array, as parameter to other

Tags: java, annotations

I’ve some annotations like

```
@A
@B
@C
```

... and which to declare another annotation like

```
public @interface Markers {
    public ???[] value();
}
```

...then use it as in the below example

```
@Markers({
    @A,
    @B,
    @C
})
```

I’ve try replacing `???` with `Annotation` or `Class<? extends Annotation>` but first doesn't work and second doesn’t provide an instance (NB: @A, @B & @C may have some attributes)?

NB : Because some constraints, I can not declare `Markers` as ...

```
public @interface Markers {
    public A valueA();
    public B valueB();
    public B valueC();
}
```

Please help !

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible in Java, you only can have arrays of one specific annotation type as annotation members.